# Import word file with angular ui tinyMCE

Tags: angularjs, text, import, tinymce

Is there a way to import a local word file into the text area created with the Angular UI TinyMCE directive?

Comment: is possible to convert word file in html using angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE has a `Paste` plugin that will clean up a great deal of the messy HTML that gets generated by MS Word documents. You need to make sure you load the `paste` plugin in your configuration for TinyMCE.

TinyMCE does not have any sort of "import" function that will open a Word doc and import the content into TinyMCE.

Comment: there is a way to import a word file and convert it to html in angularjs (and then attach this converted file to a model)? can you address me to some examples? thanks

Comment: @PierpaoloCroce I don't know of any tooling to do that - if would be outside of what TinyMCE does for sure.